# Fitting GARCH Model

Tags: time-series, estimation, maximum-likelihood, garch, estimators

I'am getting more and more familiar with this kind of model (and others models too).
I'm now used to fit this model with my data (rmgarch package in R).

How is it done ? What is the theory behind parameters estimators ?

I think about a maximum likelihood process, but I would like a confirmation and precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is a very comprehensive topic. Since you use the rmgarch package, I assume, that you fit a multivariate GARCH model? In this case, you should have a look at the corresponding [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/rmgarch.pdf).

Developer details can be found at the [crantastic](http://crantastic.org/packages/rmgarch) page. If you really want to go into detail, you have to look at a multivariate GARCH book, e.g. [Lütkepohl](http://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Multiple-Time-Series-Analysis/dp/3540262393). If you want to know, how the implementation is done,  you have to check the code, which is published [here](http://code.google.com/p/rmgarch/).